# Xserver: any way to offset OLED burnout (filter specifc pixels)?

Tags: xrandr, x-server

Any already coded way (that is apps) for Xserver to filter specific pixels of input to e.g. offset OLED burnout (also make dead pixels on LCD black)?

I understand that might reduce color depth in similar way to software brightness control via `xrandr`. P.S. That's where >8 bits color is very beneficial.